# Connecting to remote sql server not on LAN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running sql server 2012 on my local network (LAN) and its working perfectly. Now i need my remote computers (not on LAN) to connect with this server. What do I need for that? do i need static ip for the server? Plz tell me the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a static IP for the connection itself, but if you have a dynamic IP then you need a way for the remote computers to know what the IP is, e.g. a [dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS).

Comment: Are you talking about the site like noip.com?

Comment: @Junaid: Yes, that's one example. Here are some more: https://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Internet/Protocols/DNS/Service_Providers/Dynamic_DNS/

Comment: can you please tell me what role VPN can play? I mean to say can this problem be solved by making VPN?

Comment: @Junaid: No, the VPN also needs an address to connect to, so it would only move the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to configure client location Router settings, then open SQL server tcp port( 1433 ) or Udp port (1434 ) in that location.

Follow these steps

1:Go to the router settings.

2:Now go to NAT link then enter your System's IP and SQL server port then click save & apply.

Now in web.config file your connection should be like this

```
connectionStrings>
        <add name="dbconnection" connectionString="Data Source=tcp: remote location ip (public ip address),1433;Initial Catalog=Education;uid=sa;pwd=123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```